# How to add image file as Ole object in excel using java

Tags: excel, aspose, createoleobject

I tried with Aspose cell.
But I am able to add pdf file properly.
When I add jpg file, it shows in the excel file but doesnot get opened.

I tried with following way.

```
sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setImageData(binary);
            sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setLeftCM(oleObjectIndex);
            sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setDisplayAsIcon(true);
```

Here image shown like a thumbnail , but I dont want that.

```
sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setObjectData(binary);
            //sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setFileType(oleFileType);
            sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setDisplayAsIcon(true);
            sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setLeftCM(oleObjectIndex);
```

Here it shows proper icon for the file but file does not get opened when double clicked.

Help from the community is highly apraciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following two lines of code that you also need to add:

```
sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setFileFormatType(FileFormatType.UNKNOWN);
sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjectIndex).setObjectSourceFullName(path);
```

Here is complete sample code that I tested and it works fine:
e.g

**Sample code**:

```
// Get the image file.
String path = "e:\\test\\myfile.jpg";
File file = new File(path);

// Get the picture into the streams.
byte[] img = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read(img);

// Instantiate a new Workbook.
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

// Get the first worksheet.
Worksheet sheet = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);

// Add an Ole object into the worksheet with the image shown in MS Excel.
int oleObjIndex = sheet.getOleObjects().add(14, 3, 200, 220, img);
OleObject oleObj = sheet.getOleObjects().get(oleObjIndex);

// Set embedded ole object data and other attributes.
oleObj.setObjectData(img);
oleObj.setDisplayAsIcon(true);
oleObj.setFileFormatType(com.aspose.cells.FileFormatType.UNKNOWN);
oleObj.setObjectSourceFullName(path);

// Save the excel file
wb.save("f:\\files\\tstoleobject1.xlsx");
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you so much Amjad. This solution has worked exactly as I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

i just use the same code,but i found when i open the new Excel,it shows as a image,i have to check it twice to transfer it to an OLE.
whats worry

Comment: I guess this is MS Excel's behavior where you have to double-click on the embedded ole object to open it. Anyways, could you share your current Excel file (containing the OLE Object) and you expected file (you may create your desired Excel file with ole object manually in MS Excel)? We will check it soon.